# Pasar valor a vista parcial `<partial name="">` (o fichero.cshtml) en MVC Razor de Dot-Net

Tags: javascript, mvc

¿Es posible pasar un parámetro a una vista parcial en MVC Razor? Pasarle el valor directamente desde la vista donde se invoca la vista parcial mediante el tag `<partial name="">`:

```
<partial name="newField_Dissabled.cshtml" id="insertRow" />
```

Tengo una batería de elementos de vistas parciales en mi vista principal tal como:

```
<partial name="newField_Dissabled.cshtml" id="insertRow" [arg="1"-->Esto me gustaría hacer]/>
<partial name="newField_Dissabled.cshtml" id="insertRow" [arg="2"]/>
                                  . 
                                  .
                                  .
<partial name="newField_Dissabled.cshtml" id="insertRow" [arg="N"]/>
```

La vista parcial se muestra así (teniendo en cuenta que el sufijo "_N" es lo que busco conseguir incluir de manera dinámica):

```
    <div class="row" id="newField">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input asp-for="NombreDeCampo" class="form-control" placeholder="Campo Obligatorio" id="name_N"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="NombreDeCampo" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input asp-for="NombreDeCampo" class="form-control" placeholder="Campo Obligatorio" disabled id="dataType_N"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="TipoDeDato" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input asp-for="LongitudMaxima" class="form-control" placeholder="*" disabled id="length_N"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="LongitudMaxima" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input asp-for="Precision" class="form-control" placeholder="*" disabled id="precision_N"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Precision" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input asp-for="Escala" class="form-control" placeholder="*" disabled id="escala"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Escala_N" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input asp-for="ClavePrimaria" class="form-control" disabled id="PK_N"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="ClavePrimaria" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input asp-for="ClaveForanea" class="form-control" disabled id="FK_N"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="ClaveForanea" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus newRow" disabled/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

Donde, como se puede apreciar, los "id's" generados me gustaría que se generaran dinámicamente con el sufijo "_N" haciendo referencia a el pase de parametro a través del tag mostrado anteriormente.

He encontrado que mediante el HtmlHelper "@Html.RenderPartial" o "@Html.Partial", no recuerdo, es posible pasar parámetros, pero claro, desde un controlador...

Un saludo, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, he hallado la solución utilizando el modelo de la vista, para ello, me he basado en esta solución:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799658/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-a-partial-view-in-mvc-4

Primeramente, he instanciado el modelo (puesto que todavía no lo he utilizado en la página, posteriormente lo cambiaré ya que será enviado a través del controlador), después, he introducido en el modelo el valor de indice que me interesa y por último, he enviado el modelo a la vista parcial para poder hacer uso del valor deseado.

El código es:

Modelo:

```
public partial class TableEditor
{
    public int RowId { get; set; }
    public string NombreDeTabla { get; set; }
    public string TipoDeDato { get; set; }
    public string NombreDeCampo { get; set; }
    public int? LongitudMaxima { get; set; }
    public int? Precision { get; set; }
    public int? Escala { get; set; }
    public bool? ClavePrimaria { get; set; }
    public string ClaveForanea { get; set; }
    public string IdNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Instanciación y asignación de valores en la vista principal:

```
    @{ Conocimiento.Models.TableEditor mdl = new Conocimiento.Models.TableEditor();}
    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        mdl.IdNumber = i.ToString();
        <partial name="newField_Dissabled.cshtml" model=mdl />
    }
```

Finalmente, en la vista parcial hago uso del modelo...

```
@model Conocimiento.Models.TableEditor
    <div class="row" id="newField">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input asp-for="NombreDeCampo" class="form-control" placeholder="Campo Obligatorio" id="name @Model.IdNumber"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="NombreDeCampo" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input asp-for="NombreDeCampo" class="form-control" placeholder="Campo Obligatorio" disabled id="dataType @Model.IdNumber"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="TipoDeDato" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input asp-for="LongitudMaxima" class="form-control" placeholder="*" disabled id="length @Model.IdNumber"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="LongitudMaxima" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input asp-for="Precision" class="form-control" placeholder="*" disabled id="precision @Model.IdNumber"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Precision" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input asp-for="Escala" class="form-control" placeholder="*" disabled id="escala @Model.IdNumber"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Escala" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input asp-for="ClavePrimaria" class="form-control" disabled id="PK @Model.IdNumber"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="ClavePrimaria" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input asp-for="ClaveForanea" class="form-control" disabled id="FK @Model.IdNumber"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="ClaveForanea" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus newRow" disabled/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---